# custom session_end redirect implementation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm working within an MVC app.  I have a requirement that when the session ends, the app should redirect to the homepage.  I need to implement this logic generically.

I did some research and it looks like 1 requirement is that I need to set anything to session in Session_Start in global.asax. Then Session_End in global.asax should get triggered when the session expires. On session end I need to ensure:

1. User gets redirected to the Login page.  I can redirect to the base url in Session_End to accomplish this.
2. When the user logs back in s/he should be redirected to the page that he was on when the session expired

What would be the best way for me to accomplish #1 and #2 above?

```
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["X"] = 1;
    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: are you familiar with JavaScript..? can you show us currently what you have and or have tried on your own..?

Comment: I'm pretty advanced in javascript but this seems like something I would want to implement via Session_Start/Session_End.  I put this code above.  There's nothing in Session_End yet b/c that's where I'm looking for input/feedback

Comment: you should be able to write your redirect code in the `Session_End` I would think.. but where are you ending the session..?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the session ends automatically based on a timeout config setting in Web.config

Comment: I was thinking about manually ending it like when they want to exit an entire web page with an exit button.. and you're correct it would end automatically once the timeout has been reached in regards to the session .. we do something similar to this in `Angular.js` but it keeps them on their current page so that they do not have to do all the re-navigating

Answer (score 0):

A redirect can only be issued in an HTTP response (it is a response header, typically a 302 status).  An HTTP response can only be sent in reaction to an HTTP request.  So if you want to redirect a browser, you can only do it when they request the next page.  When the session_end event occurs, you can't magically reach out the browser and make it do something.

Handling this as a server side event is not the right approach.  You will need to add Javascript to the page to keep track of the session time remaining and use [location.href](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) instead of using a redirect. For example, for a ten-minute timeout, you could use something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.href="https://www.example.com/timeout.aspx"; }, 600000);
```